# Проблема с отображение svg иконок спрайта в HTML

Tags: css, svg, svg-спрайт, спрайт

Кто сталкивался со следующей проблемой?

Есть иконки соц. сетей, в формате svg. Нарисованные в Иллюстраторе. Вот пример кода одной из иконок:

[image: картинка 1]

Вот так она должна выглядеть:

[image: картинка 2]

При помощи gulp-svg-sprite, gulp-svgmin, gulp-cheerio, gulp-replace  создаю спрайт и вставляю его в html:

[image: картинка 3]

Когда сборка запускается и открывается страница в браузере я вижу следующую картину:

[image: картинка 4]

Получается, что круг и иконка внутри круга полностью залиты чёрным цветом.
Проблема в том, что при изменении стилей у иконки (fill-opacity, stroke и stroke-width) меняются оба объекта (круг и логотип внутри круга):

[image: картинка 5]

Если вставлять инлайн, то иконка отображается корректно.
Если удалить в коде svg иконки все стили, а сверху добавить строчку, указывающую на внешнюю таблицу стилей `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="..."?>`, то всё равно заливка остаётся.

Как грамотно сделать нормальное отображение иконки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, выклаывайте код текстом

Comment: Хорошо, впредь буду выкладывать код текстом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Вы должны добавить спрайт в HTML при помощи `object`:

  ```
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="sprite.svg">
     Your browser does not support SVG
  </object>`
  ```
- Далее можно вызывать иконки из спрайта внутри HTML:

  ```
  <div>
   <svg viewBox="0 0 57 57">
    <use xlink:href="#dribble" ></use> 
   </svg> 
  </div>

  <div>
   <svg viewBox="0 0 57 57">
    <use xlink:href="#facebook" ></use> 
   </svg> 
  </div>
  ```

  **upd** Спрайт уже добавлен в DOM, поэтому необязательно указывать его при вызове иконок.

Вы правильно сделали, что указали в спрайте ссылку на внешнюю таблицу стилей

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="..."?>
```

Вы правильно сделали, что удалили стили из спрайта, так как внутренние стили команд SVG имеют наивысший приоритет по сравнению со стилями во внешних и внутренних таблицах CSS

- Добавьте еще во внешнюю таблицу стилей принудительное наследование:

  ```
  svg path {
    fill:inherit; 
    stroke:inherit; 
  }
  ```

*Теперь можно управлять стилями иконок из внешней таблицы CSS.*

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! К сожалению проблема не была решена, видимо я что-то делаю не так.
Я добавил спрайт в HTML с помощью object.
`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/icons/symbol/sprite.svg">
        Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
<svg class="dribbble" viewBox="0 0 57 57">
        <use xlink:href="#dribbble"></use>
</svg>`
Добавил во внешнюю таблицу CSS принудительное наследование, как Вы и писали.
Но в результате получилось следующее http://joxi.ru/12MExlah4WJQZ2
При попытке управлять стилями иконок из внешней таблицы CSS ничего не происходит. В чём я мог ошибиться?

Answer (score 3):

*Писал ответ на вопрос в комментариях,- не вошло. Поэтому оформляю как, отдельный ответ, может будут дополнительные вопросы по наладке, буду отвечать здесь.*

- Пробуйте вынести `object` наружу из под тега `<a>` он должен
  добавляться в HTML, DOM, как самостоятельный элемент.
- А вот при вызове иконок  можно уже обернуть svg в теги `<a> <svg> <use>.. </use> </svg> </a>`
- Внешнюю таблицу стилей, которая управляет svg лучше разместить в той
  же директории, что и Index файл HTML, к этому особо чувствителен
  `Chrome`
  Вы её можете сделать специально для SVG и потом через import
  добавить к основной таблице стилей.
- Смотрите другие  ответы по спрайтам. У ребят рано или поздно
  получилось всё.

  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82

Comment: Alexandr_T Огромное спасибо за детальное разъяснение!!! Всё получилось.

Comment: @Нияз рад за вас! Обращайтесь, помогу, если смогу :-) Для меня, где конкретно была загвоздка?

Comment: Alexandr_T вынес <object> отдельно, а внутри тега <a> уже вызывал <svg>. Загвоздка была в <object>)