# Svg use xlink не отображается в firefox

Tags: svg, firefox, svg-спрайт

Svg берется из спрайта

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
        <symbol id="cw_svg_like" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
            <path d="m107.50674,0.343053c-12.701078,0 -24.59057,5.750621 -32.506733,15.385707c-7.916163,-9.635414 -19.805327,-15.385707 -32.506733,-15.385707c-23.210382,0 -42.093616,18.882906 -42.093616,42.093616c0,18.17494 10.837545,39.197155 32.210955,62.482629c16.448475,17.919496 34.341738,31.794177 39.433908,35.619945l2.954502,2.219647l2.954502,-2.219319c5.092171,-3.825768 22.986089,-17.700121 39.434892,-35.619617c21.374066,-23.285474 32.211939,-44.308016 32.211939,-62.483285c0,-23.21071 -18.883234,-42.093616 -42.093616,-42.093616zm2.634458,97.924189c-13.529388,14.739061 -28.085146,26.653803 -35.142175,32.145044c-7.056701,-5.491241 -21.611803,-17.406311 -35.141191,-32.145372c-19.378055,-21.111407 -29.620765,-40.417321 -29.620765,-55.830245c0,-17.786035 14.470172,-32.256207 32.256207,-32.256207c11.704549,0 22.511926,6.379232 28.204834,16.648502l4.301899,7.760404l4.301899,-7.760404c5.69258,-10.268943 16.499958,-16.648502 28.204834,-16.648502c17.786035,0 32.256207,14.469844 32.256207,32.256207c0,15.41358 -10.243038,34.719494 -29.621749,55.830573z"/>
        </symbol>
</svg>
```

И вставляется на страницу

```
svg
 use(xlink:href="./images/cw_sprite.svg#cw_svg_like")
```

При таком методе svg не отображается в Firefox. На стеке уже есть подобная тема, но решение из нее мне не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не помогло, потому-что надо немного изменить ваш код вызова иконок из спрайта

```
<svg viewBox ="0 0 48 48">
 <use xlink:href="./images/cw_sprite.svg#cw_svg_like"></use>
</svg>
```

а перед этим нужно  **обязательно добавить** спрайт в HTML с помощью тега `<object>`

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="sprite.svg">
   Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/748397/28748) подробно разбиралась тема добавления иконок из спрайта.

Comment: Вам нет цены! Спасибо)