# SVG-спрайты. Не все иконки грузятся

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, svg-спрайт

Использую на сайте svg-спрайты. Иконок достаточно много (около 100), и с отображением 99% иконок нет никаких проблем. Но некоторые не подгружаются, или подгружаются на одной странице, а на другой - нет.
 В консоли выводит ошибку `500 (Internal Server Error)` (именно на подгрузку спрайта).
 Есть предположения с чем это может быть связано?

Приведу  пример конструкции svg-спрайта:

```
<svg  width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <defs> 
       <symbol id="icon-apple" viewBox="0 0 56 64">
          ...
       </symbol>
   </defs>
</svg>
```

Вставляю в html по айдишнику:

```
<svg class="svg-icons">
   <use xlink:href="images/svgdefs.svg#icon-apple"></use>
</svg>
```

Код неподгружаемой иконки (сгенерен через icomoon.io):

```
<symbol id="icon-education" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
    <path d="M6.66 16l13.34 8 20-12-20-12-20 12h20v4h-13.34zM0 16v16l4-4.44v-9.16l-4-2.4zM20 40l-14-8.4v-12l14 8.4 14-8.4v12l-14 8.4z"></path>
</symbol>
```

Comment: конструкция спрайта у вас правильная, стандартная. Поэтому лучше привести здесь полный код svg иконки, которая не грузится. Второй вопрос к вам - В Firefox проверяли работоспособность? Так  как именно этот браузер наиболее правильно работает со спецификацией SVG. Если вообще не будет работать в `FF` значит отражение иконок в Chrome результат новых технологий, которые только запутывают разработчиков и не дают кроссбраузерности. Третье - добавьте сначала svg файл спрайта, а затем вызывайте из него иконки с помощью команды `<use>`

Comment: проверил FF - та же история. Не грузятся только три иконки - стандартные стрелки для карусели и еще одна кастомная, её код добавлю в вопрос. Что интересно, те же стрелки в карусели абсолютно беспроблемно грузятся на другой странице. `owl-carousel-2`, добавляю их через navText.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Сначала нужно обязательно добавить спрайт в HTML с помощью тега
  `<object>`

  `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/svgdefs.svg">
    Your  browser does not support SVG 
  </object>`

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/748397/28748) 
   подробно разбиралась тема добавления иконок из спрайта.

- Далее вызываете иконки по `ID`

  `<svg class="svg-icons"> 
  <use  xlink:href="images/svgdefs.svg#icon-apple"></use> 
  </svg>`

### Update

Данная конструкция файла спрайта - избыточна

```
<svg  width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <defs> 
       <symbol id="icon-apple" viewBox="0 0 56 64">
          ...
       </symbol>
   </defs>
</svg>
```

Секция `<defs> ... </defs>` выполняет в svg роль библиотечного хранилища.

В этот раздел обычно помещают готовые фрагменты кода, которые могут быть использованы многократно и пока фрагмент кода не вызван с помощью команды
 `<use xlink:href=#.. ></use>` он не виден и не участвует в ходе выполнения программы.

Теги `<symbol> ... </symbol>` выполняют ту же роль, что и `<defs>` - скрывают фрагмент кода до вызова командой `<use>`

Главное отличие   `<defs>` от `<symbol>` - в возможности у тега символа использовать дополнительный `viewBox`, который дает возможность дополнительного масштабирования и позиционирования элементов SVG.

У `CHRIS COYIER` [есть прекрасная статья на эту тему](https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/).

Comment: Вопрос решен, тег `<object>` действительно помог.

Comment: раз уж вы сюда заглянули, более скиллового человека по svg мне найти. Есть еще одна проблема со спрайтами - галп в процессе сборки проекта обходит файл стороной, приходится пилить его сразу в билде, что не очень удобно. Сталкивались ли вы с такой проблемой?

Comment: @Игорь спасибо за оценку. Но к сожалению галп не пользуюсь. Только в планах изучить досконально и сделать обзорную статью на своем сайте для помощи людям.

Comment: вас понял, спасибо за помощь! :)