# Как правильно подключить svg внешним файлом?

Tags: вёрстка, svg, svg-спрайт

Не могу понять, как подключить, чтобы нормально работало.
 Делаю все по статье из этого [сайта](http://dreamhelg.ru/2017/02/symbol-svg-sprite-detail-guide/) и прекрасно все работало, до того момента, как подключил внешним файлом. Иконка не отображается на странице, хотя когда подключал этот же код спрайта на странице, то все работало.

На html странице код такой:

```
<svg class="inline-svg-icon">
<use xlink:href="test.svg#cloud"></use>
</svg>
```

Во внешнем файле test.svg код:

Comment: Начнём с того, что у вас в svg два одинаковых id, так делать нельзя

Comment: Только что удалил id из path, это просто код из примера статьи, не обратил на это внимания. А дальше что делать? )

Comment: А дальше [mcve] и никаких скриншотов кода

Comment: А так сойдет, если выложу архив на файлы в облаке?https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HXkz53VyF2NVf6J03OlprChIiSIkRuz-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Нет, архив не сойдёт, освойте редактор текста вопроса :)

Comment: Тем не менее я открыл ваши же файлы из вашего же архива — облако там отлично отображается краснозелёными цветами.

Comment: А на самом деле причина неработоспособности у вас написана в консоли в инструментах разработчика в браузере

Comment: Ошибка из консоли пропала после того, как из use удалил #cloud, тоесть удалил коккретное обращение к спрайту в файле. Но как теперь обратиться к спрайту?

Comment: Нужен ли спрайт? Я решил через подстановочные строки, работает. 

`let bit = \`<svg ....>....</svg>\``  
,затем
`document.querySelector('.inline-svg-icon').appendChild(bit);`

Answer (score 3):

> Иконка не отображается на странице, хотя когда подключал этот же код
>   спрайта на странице, то все работало.

Действительно, непосредственное встраивание svg (инлайн) в `HTML` является самым простым и надежным способом, НО
Код странички получается очень большим, поэтому более предпочтительно подключать SVG внешним файлом.
Инструкция, на которую вы ссылались хорошая, но автор не раскрыл достаточно полно, как подключать внешний файл SVG.

- Сначала нужно обязательно добавить спрайт в HTML с помощью тега
  `<object>`

  `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/svgdefs.svg">
    Your  browser does not support SVG 
  </object>`

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/748380/28748) 
   подробно разбиралась тема добавления иконок из спрайта.

- Далее вызываете иконки по `ID`

  `<svg class="inline-svg-icon"> 
  <use  xlink:href="test.svg#cloud"></use> 
  </svg>`

С производительностью тоже не будет проблем, потому-что спрайт загружается только один раз, а иконки можно многократно вызывать из него в любом месте HTML странички.

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с похожей проблемой в браузере Chrome.

В итоге оказалось, что все работает (и без `<object>`), если *svg*-файл грузится с сервера, а не локально.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше прямо в HTML встраивать, чтобы не плодить лишних запросов к внешнему SVG файлу. Однако, если вставлять inline способом, то кешироваться не будет.
На одной конференции Яндекса советовали вставлять через JS, чтобы они кешировались. 
Сейчас опишу, как я делаю.
1) Создаем JS файл с inline SVG. К примеру, такой
// Тут хранятся иконки в SVG

```
var icon = '
<svg style="display:none;">\
  <defs>\
    <symbol id="header-phone" viewBox="0 0 850.394 850.394">...</symbol>\
  </defs>\
</svg>';
```

// Вставляем иконки в HTML

```
document.getElementById('svg-icon-placeholder').innerHTML = icon;
```

2) Создаем в HTML пустой `div` с `id svg-icon-placeholder`. В него мы и будем вставлять SVG
3) Юзаем через use :)
Довольно просто, но я пока не придумал как автоматизировать сборку спрайтов через GULP таким способом. Если знаете, то подскажите как)

Comment: А заказчики не ругаются, когда вставляешь svg код прямо в html?