# Как кроссбраузерно отображать SVG спрайты в HTML

Tags: html, svg, svg-спрайт

Сразу скажу, что перечитал кучу ресурсов и кучу тем, в т.ч. [Проблема с отображение svg иконок спрайта в HTML](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748380/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-svg-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-html/748397#748397), но так и не нашел ответа. Проблема такова: при инлайновом способе загрузки SVG, а потом через

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 57 57">
     <use xlink:href="#facebook" ></use> 
</svg>
```

возникает проблема в ряде версий `FF` (в частности 52 версия), которая заключается в том, что иконки из заинлайненного спрайта показываются только на главной. Проблема с тегом base, но нормального решения без удаления этого тега никто не предложил.
`Alexandr_TT` предлагает использовать `object` вместо inline

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="sprite.svg">
    Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

но тогда конструкция подключения через use работает только если ей в xlink:href прописать ещё и путь "path/to/sprite.svg#facebook", но при таком раскладе тогда object не нужен ВООБЩЕ, потому как спрайт грузится и так, и это создает другую проблему: внешние файлы svg подобным образом загруженные не работают в IE (можно, конечно, тогда подключить SVG4everybody.js, но хочется безкостыльно решить эту задачу). Собственно вопрос: как победить старые версии мозиллы без удаления тега base или как использовать короткие пути xlink:href="#facebook" вместе с подключением спрайта через object.

Answer (score 3):

**Инлайн подключение:**

`style="display:none"` стиль, который вы используете для сокрытия элементов спрайта лучше убрать. Для этой цели в спрайте стандартно используется тег `<symbol>`, который скрывает элементы `svg` до вызова их командой `<use>` в любом месте HTML документа

Ниже пример, который одинаково хорошо работает во всех браузерах, включая **IE**

```html
<div class="row">
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  width="600" height="245" viewBox="0 0 1200 490">
   
   <symbol id="icon-arrow-left">
     <path fill="none" stroke="#b89d67" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="9" d="M126.01 242.48L6.36 122.83 126.01 3.18"/>
   </symbol> 

     <symbol id="icon-arrow-right">
     <path fill="none" stroke="#b89d67" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="9" d="M3.18 3.18l119.65 119.65L3.18 242.48" />
     </symbol>

     <use x="0" xlink:href="#icon-arrow-left" />
  <use x="850" xlink:href="#icon-arrow-right" />
  
</svg>
<div>
```

Инлайн подключение самый надёжный способ добавления SVG в HTML, но если код SVG очень большой, то его обычно добавляют как отдельный файл SVG с помощью тега `<object>`
Есть и [другие способы добавления](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047) svg в HTML

**Подключение с помощью `<object>` svg файла (спрайта) к HTML**

Если хотите получить короткий путь для вызова иконки из спрайта, то разместите файл svg в одной папке с индексным файлом, если файл будет расположен в другой папке необходимо указывать полный путь.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/sprite.svg">
    Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

`Chrome` использует сейчас новые технологии, в частности вызов иконок по `ID` без предварительной загрузки спрайта через `<object>` но это работает только в `Chrome`

Поэтому для кроссбраузерности всегда используйте `<object>` затем вызывайте иконку из спрайта:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 57 57">
     <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#facebook" ></use> 
</svg>
```

Firefox наиболее правильно воспроизводит svg, поэтому, если в нем не работает, то значит нужно искать ошибку.
Хуже всех понимает svg `IE` В частности он неправильно (по своему) масштабирует, позиционирует svg.  Поэтому двойное масштабирование, позиционирование - в шапке svg файла и при вызове иконки  `<svg viewBox="0 0 57 57">` может привести к исчезновению изображения.

Comment: Где-то в одном из своих постов здесь Вы писали, что при использовании object мы можем вызывать иконки через use, не указывая путь(xlink:href="#facebook"), но на деле без пути не работает. Та информация была ошибочной? Прямо сейчас тестирую в разных браузерах (FF52, IE11 и др) без указания object, и везде, кроме IE (для которого таки пришлось подключать svg4everybody.js), работает. Просто файл один раз скачивается, а потом используется для всех иконок. Поэтому всё-таки непонятно, для чего здесь object должен служить, если у нас и так спрайт скачивается и без него?